# How to Authenticate with facebook and twitter to the firebase in flutter?

Tags: facebook, authentication, flutter, twitter, dart

I'm trying to authenticate with faceboook and twitter , & done with setUp part of [facebook Developr console](https://developers.facebook.com/)  and implemented facebook login method to dart code but why there is occurring an error at
`facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermission`.
but I'm following the dart packages site [facebook_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login#-readme-tab-) Plugin

**Code:**

```
 Future<FirebaseUser> signInWithFacebook()async{
   FacebookLogin facebookLogin = new FacebookLogin();
   final FacebookLoginResult result = await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);
 }
```

[image]

**Twitter auth method**

```
Future<bool> signInWithTwitterAccount()async{
  setState(() {
     isLoading=true;
   });
    try{
    TwitterLogin twitterLogin = new TwitterLogin(
      consumerKey: consumerApiKey,
      consumerSecret: consumerSecretApiKey
    );
    TwitterLoginResult  _twitterLoginResult = await twitterLogin.authorize();
     TwitterSession _currentUserTwitterSession = _twitterLoginResult.session;
     AuthCredential authCredential = TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential(
        authToken: _currentUserTwitterSession.token,
        authTokenSecret: _currentUserTwitterSession.secret
     );
     AuthResult result = await auth.signInWithCredential(authCredential);
      if(result.user== null)
        return false;
      return true;
    }catch(error){
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Log in Error at :$error");
      return false;
    }
 }
```

Twitter SignIn Button:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
     child: FlatButton(
        child: Text(Login with Twitter),
         onPressed: () async{
           bool res= await signInWithGoogleAccount();
             if(!res)
              { setState(() {
                 isLoading=false;
                });
                Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Login failed");
              }else{  
              setState(() {
                isLoading=false;
              });
             Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Logged in successfully");
                            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');  
            }
         },
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Exception ,when clicked twitter sign in button:

```
E/Twitter ( 7270): Invalid json: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><errors><error code="415">Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings</error></errors>
E/Twitter ( 7270): com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.SafeListAdapter$1.read(SafeListAdapter.java:45)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.SafeMapAdapter$1.read(SafeMapAdapter.java:45)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.parseApiError(TwitterApiException.java:110)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.readApiError(TwitterApiException.java:95)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException.<init>(TwitterApiException.java:43)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.onResponse(Callback.java:42)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6635)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
E/Twitter ( 7270): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:215)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      ... 18 more
E/Twitter ( 7270): Failed to get request token
E/Twitter ( 7270): com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: HTTP request failed, Status: 403
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.onResponse(Callback.java:42)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6635)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
I/zygote64( 7270): Do partial code cache collection, code=121KB, data=74KB
I/zygote64( 7270): After code cache collection, code=121KB, data=74KB
I/zygote64( 7270): Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
E/Twitter ( 7270): Authorization completed with an error
E/Twitter ( 7270): com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Failed to get request token
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthController$1.failure(OAuthController.java:94)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuth1aService$1.failure(OAuth1aService.java:191)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.onResponse(Callback.java:42)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6635)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
E/Twitter ( 7270):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
I/Toast   ( 7270): Show toast from OpPackageName:com.company_name.project, PackageName:com.company_name.project
E/SpannableStringBuilder( 7270): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder( 7270): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
W/ContentCatcher( 7270): Failed to notify a WebView
W/ResourceType( 7270): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems logInWithReadPermission method is not present in latest release. As seen in their repository:
https://github.com/roughike/flutter_facebook_login/blob/master/lib/flutter_facebook_login.dart

You can try to login as shown in example code, which uses "logIn" function instead of logInWithPermission, check out repository example [here](https://github.com/roughike/flutter_facebook_login/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart)

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter_facebook_login/flutter_facebook_login.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  static final FacebookLogin facebookSignIn = new FacebookLogin();

  String _message = 'Log in/out by pressing the buttons below.';

  Future<Null> _login() async {
    final FacebookLoginResult result =
        await facebookSignIn.logIn(['email']);

    switch (result.status) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        final FacebookAccessToken accessToken = result.accessToken;
        _showMessage('''
         Logged in!

         Token: ${accessToken.token}
         User id: ${accessToken.userId}
         Expires: ${accessToken.expires}
         Permissions: ${accessToken.permissions}
         Declined permissions: ${accessToken.declinedPermissions}
         ''');
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        _showMessage('Login cancelled by the user.');
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
        _showMessage('Something went wrong with the login process.\n'
            'Here\'s the error Facebook gave us: ${result.errorMessage}');
        break;
    }
  }

  Future<Null> _logOut() async {
    await facebookSignIn.logOut();
    _showMessage('Logged out.');
  }

  void _showMessage(String message) {
    setState(() {
      _message = message;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text(_message),
              new RaisedButton(
                onPressed: _login,
                child: new Text('Log in'),
              ),
              new RaisedButton(
                onPressed: _logOut,
                child: new Text('Logout'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much , but I have mention for Twitter too.
 would you please do me an another favour?
please  Provide me code for Twitter authentication or suggest me any perfect tutorial for it

Comment: hello sir, I want to Facebook authentication with the firebase.
and your code is not authenticated with firebase.

Comment: Have you done the AndroidManifest.xml changes suggested on the plugins home page. Also if you are facing any runtime error, provide the error log.

Comment: Sir, Facebook authentication to firebase has done Successfully .
but getting exception at twitter authentication.
Plesse look at code , I have edited my question.